# How do I retreive data again with $HTTP in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS $http to get data and creating a list of objects from the data returned. When the page loads $http gets and returns the data successfully. How do retrieve the data again without refreshing the page?

```
$http.get("files/data.json")
   .then(function (response) {
   // javascript to assign returned data to list of objects
}).catch(function (response) {
   console.log("error");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the $http promise:

```
var promise = $http.get("files/data.json");

promise.then(function (response) {
   // javascript to assign returned data to list of objects        
}).catch(function (response) {
   console.log("error");
   throw response;
});
```

Then extract the data again:

```
promise.then(function (response) {
   // javascript to assign returned data to list of objects        
});
```

A promise is a container that can be used as many times as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

```
angular
    .module('yourModule', [])
    .service('HTTPService', ['$http', function($http) {
        this.get = () => $http.get('files/data.json');
    }])
    .controller('yourController', ['HTTPService', function(HTTPService) {
        HTTPService.get().then(function(response) {
            // javascript to assign returned data to list of objects
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.log('error');
        }); 
    }]);
```

Then, you can inject this service wherever you want to use.